# Classloader for reflection in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I need to load some classes by reflection (for serialization purpose) into a Google Dataflow pipeline. The code runs just fine locally; but when I run it remotely on the Google Cloud it doesn't find the classes.

I am almost sure that his related to the Classloader used with the staged files. Does anyone has succeed to use reflection within a Dataflow pipeline?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()),
            ClasspathHelper.forClass(Object.class),
            PipelineOptionsFactory.class.getClassLoader(),
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
    );

Set<Class<? extends Event>> events = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Event.class);
```

Comment: Are you sure the classes you're trying to load were actually part of the staged files? If not, they won't be available on the worker and the reflection will fail.

Comment: Could you include the error messages you're getting?

Comment: I am mostly sure that the classes are part of the staging files; because they are used elsewhere in the code.

I don't get any specific error message; just `reflections.getSubTypesOf(Event.class)` return an empty Set.

Comment: Just checked the staged zip files and class files are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem with Reflections or how you are using it.

All of the staged JARs should be available on the class path, and Dataflow doesn't do anything tricky with the class loader. To verify, I created a simple test that uses the used `Class.findClass` directly to load the class. It didn't work with `Object.class.getClassLoader()`, but using any of the following did work:

- `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`
- `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`
- `PipelineOptionsFactory.class.getClassLoader()`.

I played around a little trying to get Reflections to work. I was able to do so by explicitly setting it up to (1) load my main class (`SomeClass`) and (2) to load all subtypes of that (using `SubTypesScanner`). I used the following:

```
Reflections r = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .addClassLoaders(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
             .addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClass(SomeClass.class))
             .addScanners(new SubTypesScanner()));
Set<Class<? extends SomeClass>> set = r.getSubTypesOf(SomeClass.class);
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with `Reflections` and I'm not completely familiar with how Reflections is supposed to work, but it seems like it is failing to find the classes while doing the scan, so when you ask for sub types it isn't finding them.

Comment: Following you suggestion I used a configuration builder based on your example + `ClasspathHelper.forClass(Event.class)` with the actual parent class I needed the subtypes and that did work! Thanks